# Can we loop in JSON?

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, html-table

good days everyone. I'm doing some project.I need to build table based on the day of the month. And this is part of my code,

```
for (i = 0; i < totalday; i++) {
        daytitle[i] = info[0]['monthly'].day[i] + "(" + info[0]['monthly'].date[i] + "/" + info[0]['month'] + "/" + info[0]['year'] + ")";
    }


    var cycle = info[1]['data']['process'][0]['cycle'];
    var table_th_tr1 = [{
        title: 'Weekly Temperature Record',
        align: 'center',
        valign: 'middle',
        colspan: 5,
        rowspan: 2
    }, {
        title: daytitle[0],
        colspan: cycle * 2,
        align: 'center',
        valign: 'middle'
    }, {
        title: daytitle[1],
        colspan: cycle * 2,
        align: 'center',
        valign: 'middle'
    }, {
        title: daytitle[2],
        colspan: cycle * 2,
        align: 'center',
        valign: 'middle'
```

the daytitle[ ] will goes on until 30.

```
{
            title: daytitle[30],
            colspan: cycle * 2,
            align: 'center',
            valign: 'middle'
        }];
        table_th[0] = table_th_tr1;//create column for row 1
```

So its too long. Did you guys have any idea to simplify it? im thinking of doing loops for daytitle[ ]. But I cant figure it out on how to do it.   Thank you.
[this is the output of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mexBK.png)

Comment: Please tag language

Comment: Please explain in more detail what it is you want to achive with this.

Comment: Update the question with the info not just in a comment @aqteha :) Also Please create a minium working example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully figure out on how to simplify the code.Here are the code :

```
for (i = 0; i<totalday;i++){
            table_th[0].push({  //create column for the row
                title:daytitle[i],
                colspan:cycle*2,
                align:'center',
                valign:'middle'
            })
        }
```